# I want to set the alt function for the gpio in raspberry pi

Tags: gpio, linux, rpi.gpio

I am working on the raspberry pi, doing changes in the machine driver.

And there is a hack in the machine driver to change the alt function of one gpio.

So I want to remove the hack and want to call any c fuction available in the kernel or somewhere else.

How can I do that?

My hack code is

```
static void bcm2708_set_gpio_alt(int pin, int alt)
{
  /*
   * This is the common way to handle the GPIO pins for
   * the Raspberry Pi.
   * TODO This is a hack. Use pinmux / pinctrl. 
   */
  #define INP_GPIO(g) *(gpio+((g)/10)) &= ~(7<<(((g)%10)*3))
  #define SET_GPIO_ALT(g,a) *(gpio+(((g)/10))) |= (((a)<=3?(a)+4:(a)==4?3:2)<<(((g)%10)*3))
  unsigned int *gpio;
  gpio = ioremap(GPIO_BASE, SZ_16K);
  INP_GPIO(pin);
  SET_GPIO_ALT(pin, alt);
  iounmap(gpio);
  #undef INP_GPIO
  #undef SET_GPIO_ALT
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help if you mention the purpose of the driver.

I'd leave the code alone.

The same code is used by the SPI and I2C drivers (with the same comment).

I don't think pinctrl/pinmux for the Pi supports setting general gpio modes.

I guess the place to look is linux/drivers/pinctrl/pinctrl-bcm2835.c

Comment: the purpose is, i am using GPIO2 for 2 purposes, 1st time i set it as output and i set an value to it and then i have to set the alt0 function on the GPIO2

Comment: how to use this  pinctrl-bcm2835.c file for that purpose

Comment: @vvn I don't think you can, that's why it isn't used by the SPI/I2C modules.  If the call is made frequently I'd do the ioremap at driver load and iounmap at driver unload.  I'd also change the mapped size to 0xB4 (the size of the gpio registers) rather than 16K.  Other than that I'd leave the code alone.  It's perfectly understandable by anyone using the gpios in the kernel.

Comment: But after reviewing that code my people are rejecting that hack and suggesting to do somethig like pinmux/pincontrol

Comment: As I said I think the place to look is  linux/drivers/pinctrl/pinctrl-bcm2835.c.  The function  bcm2835_pinctrl_fsel_set is an obvious candidate.  It is doing more than I would expect.  Some of the same guys who wrote that module also worked on the SPI/I2C drivers so I wonder why they didn't use that module.

Comment: yeah, i seen that function and we are unable to call that from our driver because its internal to that file and its not exposing outside. Even i dont know how exactly i have to do. I want to know that is there any generic file that will act as intermediate to the pinctrl-bcm2835.c and my machine driver ?

Comment: @vvn Ah, I didn't check to see if the function was exposed, the static passed me by.  Well that explains why it isn't used in the SPI/I2C drivers.  Surely your driver is Raspberry Pi specific?  You really need to get a code review exception.  I suppose you could try to get pinctrl-bcm2835.c updated in the kernel to expose the needed interface(s).  I suspect that isn't a practical proposition.

Comment: yeah, i am writing the machine driver of the wolfson for raspberry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19200/discussion-between-vvn-and-joan).

Comment: How can i use the pinctrl-bcm2708.c for the above operation. I saw that pinctrl-bcm2708.c is only pinctrl and not the gpio

Comment: There is example standalone code at [Minimal gpio access](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Misc_code) which shows how to set a gpio mode,

Comment: thanks joan, previously u said that we can set the function of the gpio using the function `bcm2835_pinctrl_fsel_set`, but how can we use this function to set alt functions? this function can be called from setting input and output direction functions. There is no api available for us to set the alt function. Can u suggest anything?

Comment: Pass the appropriate enum bcm2835_fsel fsel parameter.  Look in the source file.

Comment: Yes Joan, i tried that i got errors because the fsel function is static inline function. And we cant call that function from other files

Comment: I'm at a loss to know what you want.  Use any code you want to set the mode.  There is plenty available.

Comment: Hi, Joan, I searched a lot and not find any api to set the alt function for the gpio. Is there any api available in linux? Can anyone using that?

Comment: Apparently not.  You'll have to write your own and get it added to the Linux software tree if it is important to you.

Comment: Hi joan, I am trying to add the API for setting the alt function in pinctrl. From where can i get the permissions to edit the core.c and pinmux.c to commit in the linux source

Comment: I'm not sure.  It is not something I have ever done.  Do not expect this to be a straightforward exercise.  I suggest you start off by monitoring http://lists.infradead.org/mailman/listinfo/linux-rpi-kernel to get some idea of the working practices.